# How to Implement Text Recognition Service from Huawei ML Kit in Cordova and Reduce Application Size

Tags: cordova, huawei-mobile-services, mobile-development, huawei-developers, huawei-ml-kit

I would like to use the Huawei ML kit to implement the text recognition service in my Cordova project (Android). However, I only want to use this service and not all the other services offered by the kit. Currently, I am using the ML Kit plugin for Cordova, but when I generate the application, it takes about 150MB because it includes the whole kit.

`cordova plugin add @hmscore/cordova-plugin-hms-ml`

**About Service:**

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/introduction-0000001050765773-V1

**Text Recognition:**
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/text-recognition-0000001051005809

**GitHub:**

https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-cordova-plugin/tree/master/cordova-plugin-hms-ml

I would like to reduce the size of the application by removing the services from the kit that I am not using and only include the text recognition service in the final application. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I would like to know if there is any way to customize the ML Kit plugin for Cordova or if there is any other solution to achieve this goal.

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions on how I can reduce the size of the application and use only the text recognition service of the Huawei ML Kit in my Cordova project.

Comment: 150kb ? What's wrong with that

Comment: Sry 150MB* @Eric

Comment: If you're just doing text recognition, why don't you use an OCR plugin instead?